# Create a calculated column in pivot table in python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add the new calculated column in pivot table in python. The formula for that column should be like the one below:

```
math.log10(2.718281+(table['eventid']+table['nkill']+table['nwound'])/3).
```

I'm getting an error every time.
Could you, please, help me to solve this issue? Thank you!

I added the part of my pivot table. It is built by country and by year for three variables: eventid, nkill and nwound.

```
eventid nkill   nwound
Crime   Crime   Crime   Crime
country_txt iyear           
Afghanistan 1995    1   0.000000    0.000000
2001    2   1.500000    0.500000
2002    6   0.833333    0.800000
2003    36  2.117647    2.968750
2004    28  3.222222    2.538462
```

Comment: Please help us help you be showing some of your data in _text form_ in your question. See how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you are getting any error you should share error details with your question.

Comment: Can you show me the output of table.info()?

Comment: @GSazheniuk, here is the error I'm getting:TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-df7aa61b8df3> in <module>()
----> 1 TI_row=math.log10(2.718281+(table['eventid']+table['nkill']+table['nwound'])/3)

TypeError: a float is required

Comment: @ScottBoston <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 335 entries, (Afghanistan, 1995) to (Yugoslavia, 2001)
Data columns (total 3 columns):
(eventid, Crime)    335 non-null int64
(nkill, Crime)      335 non-null float64
(nwound, Crime)     335 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1)
memory usage: 10.9+ KB

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

***Cause you did not show the error code***, however, base on my understanding, usually 
two types, first int + float which is cover by `.astype(float)`, second index mismatch when you assign the new column , which is cover by `.values`, notice I using `.mean(1)` to get the average value of the row.

```
table['New']=np.log10(table.mean(1).astype(float).add(2.718281)).values
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Wen Thank you for the answer!   I have only one concern about the results as computed results are slightly different from estimated in Excel (for double check) and using other code in Python.    There is the results from the code you proposed: eventid nkill nwound New
Crime Crime Crime Crime 
country_txt iyear    
Afghanistan 1995 1 0.000000 0.000000 0.490064
2001 2 1.500000 0.500000 0.587174
2002 6 0.833333 0.800000 0.680977
2003 36 2.117647 2.968750 1.122897
2004 28 3.222222 2.538462 1.057784

Comment: @LyudmylaStarostyuk if it is worked , you can accept my answer :-)

Comment: @LyudmylaStarostyuk can you give me a screen shot for you excel result ?

Comment: @Wen Yes, it works! :) My only concern is the difference in results. For example, the first row gives 0.490 when I use your code. But the other code (TI_row=(2.718281+(table['eventid']+table['nkill']+table['nwound'])/3), TI=np.log10(TI_row)) and Excel give 0.484. Not a big difference but still not good for the research purpose

Comment: @LyudmylaStarostyuk by using excel I got the same this is the formula =LOG10((1/3)+2.718281)

Comment: @Wen Yes, I was using the same formula  =LOG10((1/3)+2.718281)=0.484. But the code gives slightly bigger number 0.490 and I have no clue why

Comment: @LyudmylaStarostyuk this is what I get from the code I provided array([ 0.48452965,  0.6076281 ,  0.7212107 ,  1.21520773,  1.14525368])